# What is the difference between a "guess" and a "hunch"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

Can both "guess" and "hunch" be used interchangeably or is there a minute difference? I know it doesn't apply to the phrase 'I guess', but generally when do you use "hunch"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Guesses* are more assertive than *hunches*. A hunch can be seen as a hint or feeling and is something that typically indicates a suspected outcome or result:

> I have a hunch that they are lying.
>
> My hunch suggests otherwise.
>
> I am only working on hunches.

The conveyed message is that there isn't much rhyme or reason behind a hunch. The only backing is... just that it exists. You very rarely have control over hunches and once you can point toward *why* you have a hunch it starts becoming less of a hunch and more of a guess.

A guess can drift from potshots to educated guesses and are considered more challengeable. Where a hunch simply describes your feelings or thoughts, a guess is expected to have some meat behind it. Asking *why* of a guess is expected. Asking *why* of a hunch is pretty pointless.

In terms of use, *guess* can be seen as a strict upgrade from *hunch*:

> I guess that they are lying.
>
> I guess otherwise.
>
> I am only working on guesses.

The scale does continue from there, but the range of *guess* is very broad and context is important:

> If you had to guess, what is the population of Mexico?
>
> I don't know the answer, but I can guess.
>
> Are you guessing?
>
> This is an educated guess.
>
> I have no idea, but my guess is five.
>
> I can guess.

Beyond *guess* are words like *answer*:

> This is my answer.
>
> What is the answer?
>
> Is that your final answer?

Comment: Interesting. I would have answered the exact opposite of this. `Guess` (without "educated" in front of it) to me implies you are no more certain about the answer than any other, but are arbitrarily picking that one. `Hunch` implies you have some reason for picking the choice you are picking. Perhaps it is a reason you can't quite articulate, but it is there.

Comment: I see the difference not so much in definite-ness but in the ability to articulate one's motivations. I can be totally indefinite in a guess, but I know why I took that guess (because the dice came up 6s, say); but if I have a hunch, I can't pinpoint why I have it.

Comment: @JPmiaou: I think the term "guess" can cover a much wider range of certainty than "hunch", though certain contexts (e.g. "just a guess" or "a lucky guess") may clarify narrow it down.  The term "guess" may apply in cases where one picks something arbitrarily at random because even a choice that may be wrong would be better than none at all, or to cases where one has a particular, strong, and well-founded belief.  "Hunch" generally implies a particular belief, but one which is not especially well-founded.

Answer (score 10):

A "hunch" is typically associated with someone having an intuitive, "gut feeling" about something.

> I have a hunch that the plants were moved by an animal.

A "guess" is usually more generic and hints at less intuition or feeling and a tiny bit more cognition.

> Can you guess who was at the party?

Comment: Actually, a "hunch" is quite often based on something more tangible than a simple gut feeling (eg: A witness being evasive. Unusual red dirt in a suspect's car, etc).

Comment: A hunch could also be more of an educated guess.  Because of other scenerios this is likely so i have a hunch it could apply here.

Answer (score 1):

For me the differentiation is that one can precede the other in only one instance, meaning a *hunch* can precede a *guess*, but a *guess* would not precede a *hunch*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If by 'precede' you mean what I think you mean, then I'll upvote your answer (if not, I guess I don't understand it! :) I think you can have a *hunch* about something before you're even conciously aware there's a question at issue that might require an answer (or *guess*). Is that what you mean? If so, you can always **edit** your answer to clarify this point.